# How to handle multiple types of exception from REST

Tags: rest, exception

I have a REST resource that can throw many types of exceptions.
In order to retrieve a pretty response when exception happens I did the following:

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public ResponseEntity<String> handleError(Exception ae) {
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(ae.getMessage(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
}
```

But from clinet side I can't recognize what type of exception was thrown!
I have some Junits with expected exception, and test cases are failing because of that in different modes.

I can add a new class for Error that will contain the exception name: ae.getClass().getSimpleName(), and the message and return it in response.

Is there a cleaner way?

Answer (score 0):

To handle multiple exception types, you could [have a look](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.java) at what Spring MVC does in the  [`ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.html) class. It handles a number of `Exception`s and check their types using `instanceof`.

---

> But from client side I can't recognize what type of exception was thrown!

> I can add a new class for `Error` that will contain the exception name: `ae.getClass().getSimpleName()`, and the message and return it in response.

You should avoid leaking this information to the client. What if you refactor your code and rename the exception classes? You will break the client code.

Instead, you should translate the exception into something that can be parsed by client (and, of course, document it properly).

Consider, for example, an `OutOfCreditException` (made up for this example) to indicate that the client's account doesn't have enough credit for a purchase. It could be translated to the following payload, which could easily be parsed by the client:

```json
{
  "error": "out-of-credit",
  "title": "You do not have enough credit",
  "details": "Your current balance is €10, but the items cost €50",
  "balance": 10,
  "currency": "EUR"
}
```

---

For reporting problems in HTTP-based APIs, also consider having a look at the [RFC 7807][4]: It defines defines a simple JSON document format for represeting problems along with the `application/problem+json` media type.